# How to deploy a new version of binary to a server when it's already running?

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, webserver, fabric

I'm trying to put a new version of my webserver (which runs as a binary) on an amazon ec2 instance. The problem is that I have to shut the process down each time to do so. Does anyone know a workaround where I could upload it while the process is still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could, you don't want to. What you want to do is:

1. Have at least 2 machines running behind a load balancer
2. Take one of them out of the LB pool
3. Shutdown the processes on it
4. Replace them (binaries, resources, config, whatever)
5. Bring them back up
6. Then put it back in the pool.
7. Do the same for the other machine.

Make sure your chances are backward compatible, as there will be a short period of time when both versions run concurrently.

Comment: Sounds good thanks. So running a standalone binary is *never* a good idea, since the only way to upgrade is to pull it offline

Comment: Correct. But mostly because servers fail all the time. All the time. And you indicated you wanted very low down time. Consider more than 2 servers, even.

Comment: Let's say I want to perform a db migration in prod. Should I point the load-balancer at a "coming soon" page on a different server, perform the migration, then point the load-balancer back to the prob web-server cluster?

Comment: It's really best if your migration is backward compatible and takes little time. For example, add a column with default values. If it's breaking then one solution is what you said. OR: you could do it "staged": create the new DB in an off-line manner, freeze changes to your DB in the mean time, and then in one step change the URL to the DB to your new DB. Another option is instead of freezing updates to your DB, just "migrate" those changes (which should be a small set) to the new DB afterwards.